# difference between calling ps1 file from console vs F5 in VS Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm writing some PowerShell 5.1 code in VS Code using the Powershell extension on Win10. I have a `.psm1` file in which I declare some classes that I use in a `main.ps1` via the `using module` directive.

When I hit F5 in the `main.ps1` file, it runs fine. However, in the console window, when I run `.\main.ps1` (RemoteSigned, it won't accept Unrestricted), it errors complaining the type (class) isn't found.

To illustrate with an example:

**main.ps1**

```
using module ".\classes.psm1" # need using module to pull in the classes, Import-Module does not do that
Import-Module ".\functions.psm1" -Force

$output = 42 | Get-Something 

$output
```

**classes.psm1**

```
Class SOSample
{
    [int]$Foo
}
```

**functions.psm1**

```
function Get-Something {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [int]
        $Integer
    )
    $retval = New-Object SOSample
    $retval.Foo = $Integer
    return $retval
}
```

When in VS Code in `main.ps1`, I can hit F5 and I get a result.
When in VS Code in the terminal, when I then run `.\main.ps1` it also runs.
However, when I close and reopen the folder, then run `.\main.ps1` from the terminal, it complains about the type `[SOSample]` not being found.

So my question is: how does hitting F5 in the .ps1 file differ from running the .ps1 from the terminal?

Comment: Please add the specific failing part of your `.\main.ps1` script and the exact error to your question. [Strict mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-7)?

Comment: PowerShell class visibility is restricted to the defining scope + scopes qualified with `using module DefiningModule`. Add `using module ".\classes.psm1"` to the `functions.psm1` module file and it'll work.

Comment: I don't think you making an equal compare, where you reopen the console (start a new session), you reusing VS Code (and probably have the class already loaded). Anyways, I agree with @Mathias comments, that should (re)load the `SOSample` class.

Comment: Thank you, that did indeed work. Doesn't quite answer my question tho (or I simply don't get it).